# Get all gmail accounts on android in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a register and login system using google account as username and I was wondering is there a way to get all google accounts on the android device as string and put them all in an array?

Comment: the repply is very extended and so much diferent parts. You need to start checking the Google api of gmail and calling a restservice from Unity3d. But the answer is yes, there a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27543114/3785314) answer which is in Java. By using `AndroidJavaClass` and `AndroidJavaObject`, you won't need a Java code and a jar/aar plugin at-all. It will all be done from C#.

```
string[] getAndroidEmailAccounts()
{
    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

    AndroidJavaClass ACManager = new AndroidJavaClass("android.accounts.AccountManager");
    AndroidJavaObject ACManagerAct = ACManager.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("get", currentActivity);

    AndroidJavaObject accounts = ACManagerAct.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getAccountsByType", "com.google");
    AndroidJavaObject[] accountArray = AndroidJNIHelper.ConvertFromJNIArray<AndroidJavaObject[]>(accounts.GetRawObject());

    string[] accountName = new string[accountArray.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < accountName.Length; i++)
    {
        accountName[i] = accountArray[i].Get<string>("name");
    }

    return accountName;
}
```

You need this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293396/3785314) post describes how to use Manifest in Unity project.

Comment: Does this still work now? I tried it but it always gives me an empty string.